# How to make multiple requests at the same time for same request id using postman

Tags: get, postman-collection-runner

I want to GET data from Postman.

I want to make 600 requests with same request id and it should be at the same time.

Is it possible to do such in Postman?

If yes, can anyone explain to me how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot do parallel requests in postman by executing a simple request.

What you can do is run the whole thing in parallel in a pre request script instead:

https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#sending-requests-from-scripts

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, [you can use JMeter](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10375/jmeter-how-to-trigger-all-multiple-requests-at-same-time). You can [convert your Postman project to JMeter](https://loadium.com/postman-to-jmeter-converter).